# Why is text being hidden behind "Featured on Meta" window?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

In [Finding the Distance Between Contours (Calculus 3 Question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387872/finding-the-distance-between-contours-calculus-3-question), what is causing the posting text to be partially hidden behind the Featured on Meta window?

[image]

Comment: This seems a bit similar to this bug report: [Long display style formulae extend too much to the right with some renderers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5255). However, that post explicitly says that it only influences Common HTML, while in this case I see the same problem as you for HTML-CSS. It is certainly non-standard that the OP typed the whole text in MathJax (even the non-math parts). But probably similar bug can manifest even for some legitimate uses of MathJax.

Comment: @Moo, the question has since been deleted, and so is visible only to users with $\geq 10,000$ in rep.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, I am happy I did a screen capture!

Comment: @Moo Good call!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While $\rm\LaTeX$ (and, well, $\rm\TeX$) is a typesetting system, MathJax is a mathematics rendering system.

One should not use MathJax for typesetting text in browsers, especially on StackExchange. (It is arguably doable if you have a static webpage, but even then you ***really*** shouldn't.)